# minipage environment inserting blank pages and footer won' turn off

Tags: minipage

This is my first post, so hopefully I got the formatting correct. I have searched all over and can't seem to find an answer to my problem. Below you will find a minimal example of my text file. I have two problems.

1: Latex is inserting a blank page prior to the `\minipage` section header page that I am creating. How do I get rid of the blank page?

2: I can't seem to shut off the footer on the second section header page (section 2). I used `\thispagestyle{empty}` but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass[hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Mapping=text-tex]{Calibri}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,9in},top=1.1in, left=1.05in, includefoot]{geometry} %SPECIFIES PRINTABLE AREA AND MARGINS
\usepackage{graphicx} %NEEDED FOR IMAGES
\usepackage{hyperref} %NEEDED FOR HYPERLINKS
%\hypersetup{
        %pdfborder = {0,0,0}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor, array} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable} %NEEDED FOR TABLES SPANNING MULTIPLE PAGES
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %NEEDED FOR NUMBERING PAGES ON RIGHT AND INCLUDING TOWN NAME IN FOOTER
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\makeatletter

\makeatother


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  %\AtTextCenter{%
  %  \makebox[0pt]{%
    %  \scalebox{9}{%
     %   \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{%
      %    \color[gray]{.8}\normalfont Draft}}}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}



\newcommand{\client}{Town } 

\newcommand{\jobno}{xxxxx-x} 

\newcommand{\toclink}{\hyperref[toc]{Go to Contents}}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{SEE}{rgb}{0.44,.65,.82}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\thispagestyle{empty} %TURN OFF PAGE NUMBER FOR TOC PAGE
\begin{center}
\tableofcontents \label{toc}
\end{center}
\listoftables
%\thispagestyle{empty} %TURN OFF PAGE NUMBER FOR TOC PAGE
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{top=0.0cm,left=18cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\rotatebox{-90}{\colorbox{SEE}{\makebox[1.5\textheight]{\rule{0pt}{32\textwidth}\textcolor{white}{\LARGE \textbf{\hspace{1cm}Section 1: Some Text}} \hfill}}}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{minipage}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\restoregeometry

\pagenumbering{arabic} %TURN PAGE NUMBERING BACK ON
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %GETS RID OF LINE ABOVE SECTION TYPICAL TO FANCYHDR
\pagestyle{fancy} %CREATES SPECIAL RULE FOR PAGE NUMBERING
\fancyfoot[C]{J/N \jobno - \client O \& M Manual \hspace{27mm} \textit{\toclink} \hfill \thepage} %THE RULE - TOWN NAME SPCC ON LEFT, PAGE NUMBER ON RIGHT

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{ \fancyhf{} \fancyfoot[C]{\client SWPPP \hfill \thepage}} %SETS FIRST PAGE AFTER TOC TO BE LIKE THE REST
%\draftwatermarkoff
%\includepdf[pages=-]{Test.pdf}
    %\draftwatermarkon


\newpage
\begin{center}
\section{Operation and Maintenance Manual Introduction} 
\end{center}
my text here    
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{top=0.0cm,left=18cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\rotatebox{-90}{\colorbox{SEE}{\makebox[1.5\textheight]{\rule{0pt}{32\textwidth}\textcolor{white}{\LARGE \textbf{\hspace{1cm}Section 2: Some Text}} \hfill}}}
\end{minipage}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\rule{0pt}{32\textwidth}`  that is a _big_ rule, did you really mean 32 times the text width there?

Comment: You shouldn't surround `\section` with `center` environment, and the `\newgeometry` and `minipage` are not doing anything useful in this context you could just use the `\rotatebox.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the only way I could get the blue vertical box the width that I wanted once I pushed it over to the right margin was by using the 32. I'm sure there is a much better way to accomplish what I am after, but I have only been messing with Latex for a few months. Not sure how to use the \rotatebox command to get what I want. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I assumed it was a typo for 0.32, 32 times the text width is bigger than the page in all directions I can't even guess what effect you intend to achieve with it? Tex can not place a rule that big so all it can do is ignore it and warn that it doesn't fit. `Overfull \vbox (350.7863pt too high) `

Answer (score 1):

Version with it integrated into the section command:

[image]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Mapping=text-tex]{Calibri}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,9in},top=1.1in, left=1.05in, includefoot]{geometry} %SPECIFIES PRINTABLE AREA AND MARGINS
\usepackage{graphicx} %NEEDED FOR IMAGES
\usepackage{hyperref} %NEEDED FOR HYPERLINKS
%\hypersetup{
        %pdfborder = {0,0,0}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor, array} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable} %NEEDED FOR TABLES SPANNING MULTIPLE PAGES
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %NEEDED FOR NUMBERING PAGES ON RIGHT AND INCLUDING TOWN NAME IN FOOTER
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\makeatletter

\makeatother


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  %\AtTextCenter{%
  %  \makebox[0pt]{%
    %  \scalebox{9}{%
     %   \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{%
      %    \color[gray]{.8}\normalfont Draft}}}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}



\newcommand{\client}{Town } 

\newcommand{\jobno}{xxxxx-x} 

\newcommand{\toclink}{\hyperref[toc]{Go to Contents}}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{SEE}{rgb}{0.44,.65,.82}

\newcommand\mysection[1]{%
\clearpage
\stepcounter{section}%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}%
\hspace*{\fill}\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\put(0,1.3){\rotatebox{-90}{\colorbox{SEE}{\makebox(11,3)[lb]{\textcolor{white}{\LARGE \textbf{\hspace{1cm}\ifnum\value{section}>0 Section \thesection\fi\quad #1}}}}}}%
\end{picture}%
\newpage
\addtocounter{section}{-1}%
\section{#1}}

\begin{document}

%\thispagestyle{empty} %TURN OFF PAGE NUMBER FOR TOC PAGE

\tableofcontents \label{toc}

\listoftables
%\thispagestyle{empty} %TURN OFF PAGE NUMBER FOR TOC PAGE
%\thispagestyle{empty}


\pagenumbering{arabic} %TURN PAGE NUMBERING BACK ON
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %GETS RID OF LINE ABOVE SECTION TYPICAL TO FANCYHDR
\pagestyle{fancy} %CREATES SPECIAL RULE FOR PAGE NUMBERING
\fancyfoot[C]{J/N \jobno - \client O \& M Manual \hspace{27mm} \textit{\toclink} \hfill \thepage} %THE RULE - TOWN NAME SPCC ON LEFT, PAGE NUMBER ON RIGHT


\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{ \fancyhf{} \fancyfoot[C]{\client SWPPP \hfill \thepage}} %SETS FIRST PAGE AFTER TOC TO BE LIKE THE REST
%\draftwatermarkoff
%\includepdf[pages=-]{Test.pdf}
    %\draftwatermarkon



\mysection{Operation and Maintenance Manual Introduction} 

my text here    


xxx


\end{document}
```

---

**Original**

[image]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Mapping=text-tex]{Calibri}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,9in},top=1.1in, left=1.05in, includefoot]{geometry} %SPECIFIES PRINTABLE AREA AND MARGINS
\usepackage{graphicx} %NEEDED FOR IMAGES
\usepackage{hyperref} %NEEDED FOR HYPERLINKS
%\hypersetup{
        %pdfborder = {0,0,0}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor, array} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable} %NEEDED FOR TABLES SPANNING MULTIPLE PAGES
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %NEEDED FOR NUMBERING PAGES ON RIGHT AND INCLUDING TOWN NAME IN FOOTER
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\makeatletter

\makeatother


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  %\AtTextCenter{%
  %  \makebox[0pt]{%
    %  \scalebox{9}{%
     %   \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{%
      %    \color[gray]{.8}\normalfont Draft}}}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}



\newcommand{\client}{Town } 

\newcommand{\jobno}{xxxxx-x} 

\newcommand{\toclink}{\hyperref[toc]{Go to Contents}}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{SEE}{rgb}{0.44,.65,.82}


\begin{document}

%\thispagestyle{empty} %TURN OFF PAGE NUMBER FOR TOC PAGE

\tableofcontents \label{toc}

\listoftables
%\thispagestyle{empty} %TURN OFF PAGE NUMBER FOR TOC PAGE
%\thispagestyle{empty}


\pagenumbering{arabic} %TURN PAGE NUMBERING BACK ON
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %GETS RID OF LINE ABOVE SECTION TYPICAL TO FANCYHDR
\pagestyle{fancy} %CREATES SPECIAL RULE FOR PAGE NUMBERING
\fancyfoot[C]{J/N \jobno - \client O \& M Manual \hspace{27mm} \textit{\toclink} \hfill \thepage} %THE RULE - TOWN NAME SPCC ON LEFT, PAGE NUMBER ON RIGHT
\fancyfoot[R]{\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\put(0,10.1){\rotatebox{-90}{\colorbox{SEE}{\makebox(11,3)[lb]{\textcolor{white}{\LARGE \textbf{\hspace{1cm}\ifnum\value{section}>0 Section \thesection\fi}}}}}}%
\end{picture}}

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{ \fancyhf{} \fancyfoot[C]{\client SWPPP \hfill \thepage}} %SETS FIRST PAGE AFTER TOC TO BE LIKE THE REST
%\draftwatermarkoff
%\includepdf[pages=-]{Test.pdf}
    %\draftwatermarkon


\newpage

\section{Operation and Maintenance Manual Introduction} 

my text here    
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

xxx


\end{document}
```

Comment: That is almost exactly what I am looking for. I am trying to set it up so that I can insert the page with the blue bar prior to the beginning of a section. You would have the blue bar page (with footer)and text in blue bar and then the next page would actually be the beginning of the section (\section). Hopefully that makes sense. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @jspaulding13 Try new version

Comment: That works perfectly until I turn on my draftwatermark (our companies letterhead). You then get an error "Dimension too large". Is there a way to get it to work with a draftwatermark? Below is the watermark code, I'm not sure how to attach a PDF so it won't work on here. Basically it is a full page with a logo in the upper left and also a logo on the bottom.

Comment: \usepackage{draftwatermark}  \SetWatermarkText{\includegraphics[width = 9.75in, angle =315]{Letterhead2.pdf}}

Comment: Didn't mean to send it like that, but hopefully you get the gist. Thanks again, you have been a huge help. I am headed out for the day, but will check in tomorrow morning.